# Editing a web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

We have an application that we want to configure deployment values under appSettings tags withing the application user interface. It seems in order to do that we need to grant application pool identity write permissions to the application root folder. We do not want to do that. Is there a way to edit a web.config file without granting the application pool identity additional permissions ?

Comment: This is probably not a good idea. If you modify the web.config file, the application will restart. If you need to modify various configuration settings, then store them somewhere else such as a separate XML or JSON config file, or in a database etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recomend you go this direction. It is really bad to edit web.config runtime. There are several reasons for this. Here is a couple of them: when you change the web.config, the application pool will be recycled, means your web-application will just re-run. All you have in session (stored in memory by default) will be vanished. This is definitely not what you need to have. Another issue is a potential security hole.

In general you have to store the settings which can be changed runtime in the exetrnal storages, like database or serialized (XML or JSON) files.

If you have the settings which should not be changed runtime, but depends on instance of web-applications then you can use web config transformations. Example, imagine, you have 5 customers and you have 5 web-applications (one per each customer) in IIS and for each of the customer you have an appSetting which is unique per customer. In this case, I would prepare different versions of the web config files using web config transformations before deployment of the web.config files to production.

Comment: Values are known in advanced so web config transformations would probably not work. Can additional XML or JSON files be located in App_Data folder?

Comment: Sure, you can put extra files into App_Data folder.

Comment: How would you populate values of appSettings in a web.config file from another file located, for example, in the App_Data folder ?

Comment: appSettings is a section inside web.config and as I said I would not change it. Instead, I would create customSettings.json and implement code to read/write the settings from/to the file.